# Symfony2 Repository Query

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I have a relationship many to many table progvol, table users, table flights
And a one-to-many table users relation rammasage
In the table rammassage I have a date field and in the table flights I have a start date I ve compare these two dates
So I write a sql query to know the date of the user of the vol table.
First j fai ds my controller to get the current user $ user = $ this-> getUser ();
And in my repositroy i did

```
    <?php

namespace PfeBundle\Repository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;


/**
 * programmevolRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class programmevolRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function getOnlyActive ($valeur,$vol)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
        $qb->where('a.users = :valeur');  // means id_user of table programmevol = $valeur($user->getId());
        $qb->where('a.vols = :vol');  // means id_vol of table vol = $vol (une instancedelaclassevol->getId());
        $qb->where('vol' , $vol);
        $qb->setParameter('valeur', $valeur);

        return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
    }


}
```

in My controller i did

```
    $comp = new CompanyEvents();

$user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
$userprogvol = $em->getRepository('PfeBundle:programmevol')->getOnlyActive($user->getId(),$comp->getId());
```

Now I have a $ userprogvol table in which I have the flight id of the programvol table + the id of the current user

Now I want to do (if $ userprog-> flights (id_vol) == $ comp-> id_vol) $ var = $ comp-> getDebt (); But $ userprogvol is an array ??

How can i do this please? Is there another trick (return type of a query is object) ??

Comment: Please take the time to fix the formating of your question, this is hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well if it is an array you could just iterate it

```
foreach ($userprog->flights() as $flight) {
    if($flight->getId() == $comp->getId()){
        //...
    }
}
```

because your variable and property naming is totaly unclear to me, this is just for let you get an idea

and it is not a simple array but an doctrine arrayCollection 
so here you have a list of available methods

http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html

maybe `$userprog->flights()->contains($element)`

is what youre really after